# Using a function callback inside another function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I have my react element with a couple of functions inside. I want to use the callback of one function inside another function as a variable. Both functions are using Fetch API.

```
fetchA = () => {
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', this.state.selectedFile, this.state.selcetedFile.name);
    fetch('/files', {method: 'POST', body: data})
      .then(response => {
        return response.json()})
      .then(function(json) {
        console.log(json));})
      .catch(function(error) {
         console.log(error)
      });
}
```

and

```
fetchB = () => {
    fetch('/trust', {method: 'put', body: **HERE**})
      .then(response => {
        console.log('SUCCESS')})
      .catch(function(error) {
         console.log(error)
      });
}
```

You can see in the body of the second fetch call is where i would like to reference the json that was generated in the response of my first function. Can anybody recommend a simple solution for this?

Comment: Do you want to call `fetchB` right away when `fetchA` is complete? Have you tried just calling `fetchB(json);`?

Comment: yes, right when fetch is done, i want to run fetchB with the response....i havent tried that yet and that was my first thought....but im new to React and wanted to make sure it was correct before trying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run `fetchB` with the result from `fetchA` right after `fetchA` is done, you can just call `fetchB` with the result of `fetchA`:

**Example**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  fetchA = () => {
    const { selectedFile } = this.state;
    const data = new FormData();

    data.append("file", selectedFile, selectedFile.name);

    fetch("/files", { method: "POST", body: data })
      .then(response => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(result => {
        this.fetchB(result);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  fetchB = data => {
    fetch("/trust", { method: "put", body: data })
      .then(response => {
        console.log("SUCCESS");
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `async/await` to make it `look` like a synchronous operation.

```js
fetchA = async () => {
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', this.state.selectedFile, this.state.selcetedFile.name);
    const response = await fetch('/files', {method: 'POST', body: data});
    return await response.json();
}

fetchB = async () => {
    const body = await fetchA();
    fetch('/trust', {method: 'put', body})
      .then(response => {
        console.log('SUCCESS')})
      .catch(function(error) {
         console.log(error)
      });
}
```